# :./gradlew: not found with docker, while hosting the host directory in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, gradlew

with below command, `docker-compose up --build`, although image is generated but when container is started, it throws an error as follows,

```
Starting da3e68163f87_khatabook-app ... done
Attaching to da3e68163f87_khatabook-app
da3e68163f87_khatabook-app | /bin/sh: ./gradlew: not found
da3e68163f87_khatabook-app exited with code 127
```

And whole log, screenshot as an attachment.

[image: Log Screenshot of build]

Below is my Dockerfile as follows,

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
WORKDIR /Khatabook\ Account
CMD ./gradlew run
```

docker-compose.yml is as follows,
version: "3.6"

```
services:
  app:
    build: ./
    container_name: khatabook-app
    volumes:
      - ./:/Khatabook\ Account
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
```

I had tried to use,

```
CMD chmod +x ./gradlew run
```

but didn't worked

My Source code root folder name is,

```
Khatabook Account
```

Comment: What is the user owning your `Khatabook Account/gradlew` directory locally ? And what is the `USER` running the container process internally ? In order to execute  `gradlew` you must give `x` permission to the `USER` inside your container.

Comment: i am quite new to docker, if possible, can u add some code

Comment: Try escaping the space in the path with a backslash: `/Khatabook\ Account`

Comment: @EzekielTemplin, now i am getting error, khatabook-app | /bin/sh: ./gradlew: not found
khatabook-app exited with code 127

Comment: locally, do `ls -al Khatabook Account/gradlew` and give the answer here. In your `Dockerfile`, replace `CMD ./gradlew run` with `CMD whoami`, run the build and give the output here.

Comment: @MichéeLengronne, -rwxr--r--  1 reprator  staff  5296 Jul 25 21:48 gradlew is the output for "ls -al gradlew" command

Comment: Ok, the `USER` inside the container is certainly not `reprator`. So you have 2 ways to achieve what you want. First way, you change the owner of `gradlew` to the one inside the container, second way you do `sudo chmod o+x gradlew` locally to give exec permissions to everybody. The first way is more secure.

Comment: @MichéeLengronne, thanks first, please let me know the first step, as i earlier said, i am quite new to docker

Comment: With the `CMD whoami` you may have a number as output (the `uid` of the `USER` inside the container). In that case, it is perfect as you can change your `gradlew` owner to this number. If not, you need to dig further to check what is the `uid` of the container `USER`. To do that, run `CMD id` instead of `CMD whoami`.

Comment: @MichéeLengronne, it will work but it will exit as soon as container is made, because, no CMD is there, now my docker file is like as follows, FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache bash

WORKDIR /Khatabook\ Account

CMD whoami

Comment: I know. That is not the final Dockerfile. It is just to investigate.

Comment: I make you temporarily replace `CMD` to find the uid inside. But you will have to put your original `CMD` back once debugged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218901/discussion-between-reprator-and-michee-lengronne).